# MySQL PDO NOW() as assigned value - is it possible?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm trying to pass a MySQL's `NOW()` function into PDO's assigned value through PHP and it's failing. I found that I must pass this directly into MySQL statement. But in my case, sometimes the `datetime` field can be empty.

Is it even possible to pass `NOW()` as PHP's assigned value?

Some code:

I'm building query dynamically and the `datetime` is dependent on some other variable's value.

```
if(isset($accountStatus)&&$accountStatus!=""){
    $tmp[':account_status']=$accountStatus;
    if($accountStatus==0){
        $tmp[':vCodeExpire']="NOW() + INTERVAL 1 WEEK";
        $tmp[':verified']=0;
    }else{
        $tmp[':verified']=1;
    }
}
```

Building SQL query:

```
$sql="";
foreach($tmp as $k=>$v){
    $sql.=str_replace(":","",$k)."=".$k.",";
}
$sql=substr($sql,0,strlen($sql)-1);
```

Then, I run PDO query:

```
$db=$pdo->prepare("UPDATE users SET $sql WHERE id=:id");
$db->execute($tmp);
```

I tried replacing double-quotes with single-quote around `NOW() + INTERVAL 1 WEEK` with no luck.
I also tried with single-quote around PDO query, but then `$sql` is passed directly, not using an assigned values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is it possible?

No.

There are 2 solutions.

1. Calculate expiration date using PHP. Something like `date('Y-m-d',strtotime('+1 week'))`
2. Create a conditional part for the query

   ```
   if(isset($accountStatus)&&$accountStatus!=""){
   $tmp[':account_status']=$accountStatus;
   if($accountStatus==0){
       $accSql = "NOW() + INTERVAL 1 WEEK,";
       $tmp[':verified']=0;
   }else{
       $accSql ='';
       $tmp[':verified']=1;
   }
   $db=$pdo->prepare("UPDATE users SET $accSql $sql WHERE id=:id");
   ```

Comment: I tried your second proposed solution and it worked perfectly. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Use `strtotime()` instead of MySQL to get date values.

Comment: It can happen that PHP and MySQL can have different time and since in this case, the time is only important in queries (later on, I also check if the time is still valid only with MySQL query), I'm only using MySQL. I don't want to deal with possible time differential between MySQL and PHP.