# PDO insert record issues

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

The insert statement using PDO displays the following errors

Fatal error: Call to undefined function NOW() in C:\xampp\htdocs\copytimeline\timeline1\insert.php

it seems that NOW() belongs in sql statements not in the array. can someone help me to fix that.

thanks

```
$statement = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO tb ( session_id,timing)
                      values
            ( :session_id,:timing)');

     $statement->execute(array(
        ':session_id' => $session_id,
                     ':timing'=> NOW()
        ));
```

Comment: `'NOW()'` must be a string

Comment: @cske actually it must not.

Comment: `INSERT INTO tb ( session_id,timing) values (:session_id,NOW())'`

Comment: @Your Common Sense you are right, won't work

Answer (score 6):

The MySQL function [`NOW()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_now) can't be passed as a variable.  You need to include it in your query.

```
$statement = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO tb (session_id, timing)
    values
    (:session_id, NOW())');

$statement->execute(array(
    ':session_id' => $session_id
));
```

See [MySQL PDO NOW() as assigned value - is it possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15968620/763468)